# How to get all Browsing data with Browsing date using windows CMD command?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, browser-history, powershell-4.0

I searched on the Internet and found a way to get all Browsing data.
Create a bat file with below-mentioned code and execute it to get all browsing data into windows power shell.

Now, I want to get all the **Browsing** **data** with the **Browsing Date** on CMD.
Is there any way to do this?

```
@echo off
Powershell -noexit "ipconfig /displaydns | select-string 'Record Name' | `foreach-object { $_.ToString().Split(' ')[-1]   } | Sort | Out-Gridview"`
```

*Here is my Output:*

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Why didn't you tag this with Powershell.  None of your code is really a batch file other than you launching a powershell command from a batch file.

Comment: `ipconfig.exe` does not capture the date, so your request is impossible. (neither does DNS, it appears)

Comment: Is there any other way to get all Browsing data?

Comment: Run a proxy server like Squid.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means a Powershell guru.  All I did was Google Search.  Using another `foreach-object` to reformat the data and adding the date seems to work.

```
Powershell -noexit "ipconfig /displaydns | select-string 'Record Name' | foreach-object { $_.ToString().Split(' ')[-1]   } | Sort -unique | ForEach-Object {$(Get-Date -Format G) + ' ' + $_} | Out-Gridview"
```

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, like I said.  I am not a Powershell guy.  I literally copied an example verbatim from the Internet and plugged it into the OP's code.

Comment: The date here is always the current date time, the expectation here is the browsing date.

Comment: @PRASOONKARUNANV yes, that was established and I put a comment above for a different solution.